# How to set scope in CXF?

Tags: java, cxf

Is there a way to set an object to be at application scope using CXF -- I'd rather not use Spring to do this.

I have a ThreadPoolExecutor set up to run tasks from incoming requests, so it needs to live at a higher scope after the request goes away.

Comment: Why not use Spring? You're getting into the area where it _is_ the easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the bus:

```
Bus bus = BusFactory.getDefaultBus();
MyClass mc = bus.getExtension(MyClass.class);
if(mc == null) {
    mc = new MyClass();
    bus.setExtension(mc, MyClass.class);
}
```